# Turbulent flow in a pipe - how to compute the friction coefficient $\lambda$

Tags: fluid-dynamics, friction, turbulence

Consider a pipe of diameter $D = 0.01$ m and Length $L = 1.0$ m represented in the figure underneath. At the in- and outlet, the pipe cross-section converges, respectively diverges smoothly. We will therefore assume developed velocity profile along the entire pipe. Water ($\mu = 0.001$ Pas, $\rho = 1000$ kg/m$^3$) is feed through the pipe from a big reservoir, maintaining the hydrostatic pressure at the entrance of the tube at a constant level approximately. Downstream, a pump is connected ot the pipe, allowing to set a specific flow rate $Q$

[image: Laval_nozzle]

The critical Reynolds number regarding the transition of laminar to turbulent pipe flow is $Re_{D, cr} = 2300$. Therefore, we consider the flow associated to the flow and high flow rate to be laminar and turbulent, respectively.

Next we apply the \textit{Bernoulli} equation with added loss term $\Delta p$ between a point of the surface of the reservoir (point 0) and point 2 at the end of the pipe

$$p_0 + \rho \frac{u_0^2}{2}+ \rho g z_0 = p_2 + \rho \frac{u_2^2}{2} + \rho g z_2$$

The pressure at the surface is the atmospheric pressure, $p_0 = p_{atm} = 101325$ Pa. Due to the big surface area the velocity $u_0$ is very small and we therefore neglect the hydrodynamic pressure at this point. Solving for the pressure in point 2 yields:

$$p_2 = p_{atm} - \rho \frac{u_2^2}{2} + \rho g h - \Delta p$$

where we used $h = z_0 - z_2$. We still have to determine the term $\Delta p$, which represents losses due to viscous shear forces. Having a smooth entrance to the pipe we assume that only losses within the pipe contribute to $\Delta p$. We can apply a general expression of the form

$$\Delta p =\rho \lambda \frac{L}{D}\frac{\bar{u}^2}{2}$$

to determine the pressure drop of a flow with constant mean velocity $u$ in a pipe with diameter $D$ and length $L$ for both laminar and turbulent flow. The friction coefficient $\lambda$ depends either only on the Reynolds number $Re_D$ (laminar flow), or on both the Reynolds number $Re_D$ and the surface roughness $k_S$ (turbulent flow, smooth pipe), or only on $k_S$ (turbulent flow, rough pipe).

[image: empiric_laws_for_pipe_flow_friction_coefficients]

Calculate the pressure $p_2$ for the following cases

1. $Q = 0.01$ l/s, smooth pipe
2. $Q = 0.5$ l/s, smooth pipe
3. $Q = 0.5$ l/s, pipe roughness: $k_{\text{S}}/D = 2e10^{-3}$
4. $Q = 0.5$ l/s, pipe roughness: $k_{\text{S}}/D = 2e10^{-2}$

Here are the **given answers** for the different flows values:

[image: answers]

Here is the code (in `Python3`) which works for the first question ($Q = 0.01$ l/s)

```
# Python 3

import numpy as np
Q = 0.01 # in l/s
Q = Q *0.001 # conversion in m^3/s
D = 0.01 #meter
L = 1 #meter
h = 4
g = 9.81 #m/s^2
rho = 1000 #kg/m^3
mu = 0.001
patm = 101325 #Pa
p1 = patm

Area = np.pi*((D/2)**2) #m^2
u_mean = Q/Area #m/s

ReD = rho * u_mean * D / mu

lambda_coef = 64/ReD
delta_p = lambda_coef * rho * L * ((u_mean)**2) / (D*2)
p2 = patm - (rho*((u_mean)**2)/2) + rho*g*h - delta_p
print("velocity: " + str(round(u_mean, 3)) + " m/s")
print("ReD: " + str(round(ReD, 3)))
print("lambda_coef: " + str(round(lambda_coef, 3)))
print("p2: " + str(round(p2, 3)) + " Pa")
print("delta_p: " + str(round(delta_p, 3)) + " Pa")
```

**My Question**

How do I have to change my code to get the correct answer 2, 3 and 4? shall I use the info about $\lambda$? Or shall I read it from a Moody diagram?

[image: Moody diagram]

Comment: Choosing a value of "1" for one of your variables is probably a poor choice, as the special properties of "1" tend to hide errors.  But, to answer your question, why don't you send correct values into your function via a parameter list in order to calculate answers 2-4?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @DavidWhite. First for the value "1": I copied the exercice given to me but I'll take note that 1 tends to hide errors. Second: can you send me an example of what you mean? you want to do a list of value Q (e.g. `Q = [0.01, 0.5]`) and run a for loop on all of them. The main problem is that the $\lambda$ is calculated differently according to roughness and that's the main problem I'm facing: I have trouble to compute the value of $\lambda$ according to rougness as presented in the table

Comment: Step 1 is to calculate the Reynolds number.  This will determine which equation to use.  What Reynolds number values did you get for cases 2, 3, and 4?

Comment: @ChetMiller, by replacing `Q = 0.01` by `Q = 0.5` you get Reynolds number of 63662 (as stated in the answer). But my question is how to compute $\lambda$. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Next step is to calculate $\frac{uk_s}{\nu}=\frac{uD}{\nu}\frac{k_s}{D}=Re\frac{k_s}{D}$

Comment: The equations for $\lambda$ in the table are transcendental equations. Solve them by numerical solution: iterating from some initial guess, say $\lambda_0$, until $\lambda_n$ no longer evolves significantly.

Comment: Thank you @ChetMiller. How would you integrate that into the code?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Gert. How would you write the code / function to iterate to find $\lambda_n$?

Comment: That tells you which of the four equations to use.  Your code needs to test for this, and then implement the appropriate choice of equation to determine $\lambda$.  This might involve using if blocks, else if blocks, and an else block.

Comment: *How would you write the code / function to iterate to find $λ_n$?* I wouldn't. I'd use a simple spread sheet for that! Even just a calculator and common sense will do.

Comment: @ecjb, there are several formulas that are used to calculate friction factor.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation

Comment: I believe I once read or saw in a YouTube video that it just keeps breaking into smaller eddies. Take a vertical pipe the height of Graham's number that is squiggly. Fill it with an ideal fluid then open the bottom end. An ideal fluid has an infinite bulk modulus and a zero viscosity. Since it's ideal, information instantaneously transmits from one end to the other. Because the pipe is finite, being stationary is not a solution and it will instantly start flowing. However, I believe it will reach a maximum speed. I think eddies will keep breaking down into smaller and smaller eddies allowing

Comment: for larger eddies to keep getting produced again and again in the fluid filled with smaller eddies. Larger eddies keep getting produced again each of which are going to keep breaking smaller and smaller allowing more larger ones to keep getting produced again and adding more and more kinetic energy to the fluid until its kinetic energy reaches something like Graham's number. You start having eddies with smaller eddies in them which have even smaller eddies in them which have even smaller eddies in them.